# UWP, Caliburn.Micro : How to pass parameters of Constructor for Method Singleton?

Tags: uwp, singleton, caliburn.micro

Here is my Caliburn.Micro code.

In first step "Configure() / App.xaml.cs" , I want to pass parameters to Constructor.

```
_container.Singleton<MySingletonClass>("KeyName");
```

MySigletonClass has a constructor with Parameter. ( 1 string only )

```
public MySigletonClass (string msg){ ...
```

How to register a Singletone with parameter ?

**Updated Question**

[With Caliburn.Micro manual](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/simple-container), There is 4 type of Register Method. Is there any type that we can pass argument ? Should I use "RegisterInstance" ?

in Manual, I really can not understand "implementation". What is this ?

```
void RegisterInstance(Type service, string key, object implementation)
void RegisterPerRequest(Type service, string key, Type implementation)
void RegisterSingleton(Type service, string key, Type implementation)
void RegisterHandler(Type service, string key Func<SimpleContainer, object> handler)
```

Comment: I'd think a singleton with parameters is not a singleton. A singleton, by definition, is an object you want to be instantiated no more than once. If you are trying to feed parameters to the constructor, what is the point of the singleton?

Comment: you are right : )  ok, I want to change Question a bit.. if you can answer, It's help me... thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Caliburn.Micro `SimpleContainer` implementation does not support constructor injection with additional parameters that can be supplied during resolution. There are other Dependency Injection containers that support that scenario, but you can easily work around this limitation by using the factory pattern.

The following example demonstrates how a `CustomerViewModel` needs the customer name as constructor parameter, but also has a dependency on a `CustomerDatabase` instance:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This is just some dependency that you want to use in your view models.
/// </summary>
interface ICustomerDatabase
{
    void DeleteByName(string name);
}

class CustomerDatabase : ICustomerDatabase
{
    public void DeleteByName(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Customer '{text}' has been deleted.");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This customer view model has a dependency on an 
/// <see cref="ICustomerDatabase"/>-Implementation, but also 
/// needs the customer name during construction for some reason.
/// </summary>
class CustomerViewModel
{
    public CustomerViewModel(string customerName, ICustomerDatabase database)
    {
        this.Name = customerName;
        this.Database = database;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public ICustomerDatabase Database { get; }

    public void Delete()
    {
        this.Database.DeleteByName(this.Name);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// To support parameters, we use the factory pattern: The factory
/// gets the view model's dependencies as its own dependencies
/// by using constructor injection. The <see cref="Create"/>-Method
/// then supplies any additional parameters. You can also use
/// multiple factory methods that correspond with different
/// constructor overloads.
/// </summary>
class CustomerViewModelFactory
{
    public CustomerViewModelFactory(ICustomerDatabase service)
    {
        this.Service = service;
    }

    public ICustomerDatabase Service { get; }

    public CustomerViewModel Create(string text)
    {
        return new CustomerViewModel(text, this.Service);
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var c = new SimpleContainer();

        // First, we register the factory and the service.
        c.RegisterSingleton(typeof(CustomerViewModelFactory), null, typeof(CustomerViewModelFactory));
        c.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ICustomerDatabase), null, typeof(CustomerDatabase));

        // Later on, we depend on the factory, not the view model itself.
        // We would use the factory as constructor parameter
        // everywhere we need to create view model instances.
        var factory = c.GetInstance<CustomerViewModelFactory>();

        // We create a view model instance using the factory.
        var viewModel = factory.Create("TestCustomer");

        viewModel.Delete();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```